# LottieAnimationView was not found in the UIManager - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, lottie

I'm trying to implement Lottie React Native into my app, but I've been having some issues. I followed the directions to install from: https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native

I've imported AnimatedLottieView and included it in my app. But I keep getting this error:

`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "LottieAnimationView" was not found in the UIManager.`

I'm running the app on a physical iPhone 14 Pro.

Comment: I am getting this same error

Comment: any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

When installing this lib, you need to recompile the app. If it's a react-native project, run:

`$ yarn start`
and then
`$ yarn android or ios`

Answer (score 0):

First check all steps of installation are done right way, then follow below steps.

1. Delete node-modules folder
2. Delete yarn.loack or npm.lock file.
3. If you are using yarn then run `yarn install` Else `npm install`.
4. Run clean build from Android studio or run this command `cd android`, `./gradlew clean`.
5. Run code form Android studio

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add lottie-ios@3.4.0
```

add this so it will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked running `npx expo install lottie-react-native`, delete `node_modules`, `yarn install` and then `yarn start`